# Creating conditions to replace missing values in pandas that include Strings, Date and Time

Tags: pandas, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements, nan

In my df I am trying to replace values in column 'Amount in (L)' based on the date and time and the Milking events that occurred that day.

```
  Milk Event          Date        Time     Amount in (L)
       Start    04/08/2001       09:00               nan 
         End    04/08/2001       10:00              1500   
       Start    04/08/2001       14:00               nan 
         End    04/08/2001       15:00              2000   
       Start    05/08/2001       08:00               nan
```

I am unsure whether to use a for loop or if statement to create conditions that replace the nan with the previous 'End' events amount. I would want it to look something like:

```
   Milk Event          Date        Time     Amount in (L)
       Start    04/08/2001       09:00                 0 
         End    04/08/2001       10:00              1500   
       Start    04/08/2001       14:00              1500 
         End    04/08/2001       15:00              2000   
       Start    05/08/2001       08:00              2000
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible you can use:

```
df['Amount in (L)'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Amount in (L)'], errors='coerce').ffill().fillna(0)
```